# Related to SubsetRandomSampler

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch

I am using SubsetRandomSampler for splitting a classification dataset into test and validation. Can we split the dataset for each class.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder( '/data/images/train', transform=train_transforms )

validation_split = .2
shuffle_dataset = True
random_seed= 42
batch_size = 20

dataset_size = len(dataset) #4996
indices = list(range(dataset_size))
split = int(np.floor(validation_split * dataset_size))

if shuffle_dataset :
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
train_indices, val_indices = indices[split:], indices[:split]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_indices)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler)
validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean train and validation not test and validation?

If so, the `SubsetRandomSampler` uses randomly select samples from indices. Therefore you can just randomly split the indices of each class before put them in `train_indices` and `val_indices`.

Like

```
indexs = [[] for _ in range(len(dataset.classes))]  # you can't use `[[]] * len(dataset.classes)`. Although there might be better ways but I don't know
for idx, (_, class_idx) in enumerate(dataset):
    indexs[class_idx].append(idx)
train_indices, val_indices = [], []
for cl_idx in indexs:
    size = len(cl_idx)
    split = int(np.floor(validation_split * size))
    np.random.shuffle(cl_idx)
    train_indices.extend(cl_idx[split:])
    val_indices.extend(cl_idx[:split])
train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_indices)
```

Answer (score -1):

"# you can't use `[[]] * len(dataset.classes)`. Although there might be better ways but I don't know"

[[]*len(dataset.classes)] works.

Comment: Try print `indexs` after the appending loop and see what happens. It is called "pointer".

Comment: ie. `indexs = [[]] * 100` then `for idx in range(1000): indexs[idx//10].append(idx)`